# Doxygen Separate Navigation/Hierarchy Page

Tags: doxygen

I'm setting up Doxygen in my codebase and want to use the Markdown support to produce a number of different 'how to' and 'design' types page in a logical hierarchy, e.g.

```
index.md
design/
    architecture.md
    database.md
how-to/
    build.md
    restore-backups.md
...etc...
```

Using the Markdown support, I can give labels to each page and then use those to link to other pages and create a page hierarchy, e.g.

```
Design {#design}
======

This section contains design documentation.

@subpage architecture
@subpage database
```

The problem I've got is that this means every level in the hierarchy needs to define which pages are its sub-pages. This litters the documentation with lots of links which I don't really need. When the hierarchy gets 3+ levels deep you end up with lots of dummy pages which only exist to define the subpages.

My question is, is it possible to define the entire navigation hierarchy in one external page so that I only have one place to define and update when new pages are added? Something like:

```
Navigation {#navigation}
=========

This page defines the navigation tree for the whole project.

@page design
@subpage architecture
@subpage database

@page how-to
@subpage build
... etc ...
```

Comment: What was the result of the solution you proposed at the end of your question?

Comment: @albert I tried it but it doesn't quite work. Firstly, you still need the placeholder pages so that you have something to link to in `\page` and `\subpage` elements. Secondly, the tree view contains the page aliases (how-to) instead of the page titles (How To...). Thirdly, you can't do it for the `mainpage`.